# Error puppet 'Hash'; expected ')' on the default at /tmp/modules/apt/manifests/init.pp:6

Tags: puppet, ubuntu-14.04

I'm taking back a project using puppet to install servers.
We have our process.pp file that work correctly

When I run

```
puppet parser validate manifests/ikuwprocess.pp
```

No error what so ever

But in the process we call apt and I get this error:

```
Error: Syntax error at 'Hash'; expected ')' at /tmp/modules/apt/manifests/init.pp:6 on node ourserver.40qyqnbkn0mu3edhynn2jlebec.ax.internal.toto.net
```

init.pp seems to be the untouched file from puppet that can be found here : https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-apt/blob/master/manifests/init.pp

But when I run the parser I got the error

```
puppet parser validate /tmp/modules/apt/manifests/init.pp
Error: Could not parse for environment production: Syntax error at 'Hash'; expected ')' at /tmp/modules/apt/manifests/init.pp:6
```

I don't know what to do... Here my OS version:

```
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=14.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=trusty
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="14.04.5 LTS, Trusty Tahr"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS"
VERSION_ID="14.04"
HOME_URL="http://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
```

And the version of puppet I'm using

```
puppet --version
3.8.7
```

What I'm doing wrong what I'm missing?

If you need more infos please tell me I'll provide it quickly

[EDIT] After a recommendation I've tryied this but still not working:

```
puppet module install puppetlabs-stdlib --version 4.21.0 
Notice: Preparing to install into /home/myaccount/.puppet/modules ... Notice: Created target directory /home/myaccount/.puppet/modules 
Notice: Downloading from https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com ... 
Notice: Installing -- do not interrupt ... 
/home/myaccount/.puppet/modules 
└── puppetlabs-stdlib (v4.21.0)
```

[EDIT] Tried to migrate to last version of puppet

```
wget -O - https://raw.githubusercontent.com/petems/puppet-install-shell/master/install_puppet_agent.sh | sudo sh

Reading package lists... Done 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  puppet-agent
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 5 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/16.8 MB of archives.
After this operation, 91.3 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Selecting previously unselected package puppet-agent.
(Reading database ... 30718 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../puppet-agent_5.3.3-1trusty_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking puppet-agent (5.3.3-1trusty) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-16) ...
Setting up puppet-agent (5.3.3-1trusty) ...
```

But when I try to call puppet:

```
puppet --version
-bash: /usr/bin/puppet: No such file or directory
```

And nothing called puppet in `/usr/bin/`

Comment: I've tried to install module concat because maybe I was in the same case in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46779302/error-when-performing-a-puppet-agent-run but still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is caused by the fact you're using an older version of Puppet (3.X) that is [EOL as of December 2016](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/puppet-users/IdutL5FTW7w), and the newer version of the Apt module uses the new [Puppet data types](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.3/lang_data_type.html) which are Puppet 4+ only.

The easiest fix will be to upgrade to the latest version of Puppet. Since the Ubuntu 14.04 upstream is an older version, I'd recommend moving to the Puppet apt repos. You can do this easily with [a script I wrote](https://github.com/petems/puppet-install-shell):

> wget -O - https://raw.githubusercontent.com/petems/puppet-install-shell/master/install_puppet_agent.sh | sudo sh

Or you can manually set up the repos for the upgrade, with the docs here: https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.3/puppet_platform.html#apt-based-systems

Comment: I feel it's the correct answer but: I've followed the installation process (one time with your script and another time withe de documentation linked) but when I launch puppet I've an error message indicating that `-bash: /usr/bin/puppet: No such file or directory` and if I check `/usr/bin/`no trace of puppet in there. What I'm missing out?

Comment: Ok I think It works (for the problem I've posted). But I needed to create the symbolic link to access to puppet `sudo ln -s /opt/puppetlabs/bin/puppet puppet` Thanks

Comment: Yep, new version of Puppet doesn't automatically add the path to your shell, that link will help :)

Answer (score 0):

Your module *puppetlabs/apt* needs as dependency *puppetlabs/stdlib* (see also https://forge.puppet.com/puppetlabs/apt/dependencies).

Add *stdlib* (i.e. with `puppet module install puppetlabs-stdlib --version 4.21.0`) to your system module path.

Comment: I've done it but I've the problem : `puppet module install puppetlabs-stdlib --version 4.21.0
Notice: Preparing to install into /home/myaccount/.puppet/modules ...
Notice: Created target directory /home/myaccount/.puppet/modules
Notice: Downloading from https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com ...
Notice: Installing -- do not interrupt ...
/home/myaccount/.puppet/modules
└── puppetlabs-stdlib (v4.21.0)`